# Function to animate an ImageView in a RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation, android-recyclerview

To forward my application, i need a function that will rotate an imageView in a recyclerView.
The recyclerView is one of 3 recyclerviews that are already working well, and are clickable through a cardView.
shortvideo there:

https://mega.nz/#!W6AyAYaY!07WG8kr_POYiGsgt0yja6fk8RaclZLw2-MiMFrmEQmk

I created Classes with a few members, which permit to know the state of the objects.

I am newbie in Android programmation, and it was difficult for me to make these recyclerView working well :-)

7 April : i finally succeeded to implement my function
but the result is weird !
can see there :
https://mega.nz/#!DzI2iaiB!VBG9Ex4TZlAsoUYPSRhXXMP4weH-9hXyjbqF1nCRyeA

There is an imageView which is rotating, but this is the left one, not the clicked one, and there is a mix, a swap between pictures.

My question is : are the imageViews clickable and focusable like cardViews ?
if so i can try to make the imageView focusable and clickable (actually the cardView is... )
What about the index is recyclerViews ? isn't it the cardview which is clicked which has the index ? or the left one in the screen ?
I am puzzled :-)

Following: the layout with CardView and imageView; MainActivity where i tried to write the function; and the Adapter for the Top RecyclerView where the function is supposed to
rotate (180 °) the imageView at the index ( index, tag and position )

```
 no change about that xml file    
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
  <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/flag_card_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flagcountry"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="W,55:100"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"/>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/flagname"
        android:layout_width="6dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/flagcountry"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
   </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

---

```
 under new kt file
   package training.geography.triplerecyclerview

    import android.provider.Settings.Global.getString
    import android.view.LayoutInflater
    import android.view.View
    import android.view.ViewGroup
    import android.widget.ImageView
    import android.widget.TextView
    import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

   class FlagAdapter(val flagcountrylist: List<FlagCard>,
              val flagitemClickListener : View.OnClickListener
              //val flagitemOnLongClickListener : View.OnLongClickListener
):
RecyclerView.Adapter<FlagAdapter.FlagViewHolder> () {
class FlagViewHolder(flagView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(flagView) {
    val flagcardView = flagView.findViewById<CardView>(R.id.flag_card_view)
    val flagcountry = flagView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.flagcountry)
    val flagname = flagView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.flagname)
}

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int):
    FlagViewHolder {
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    val viewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_flag, parent, false)
    return FlagViewHolder(viewItem)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(flagholder: FlagViewHolder, position: Int) {
    //val flagcountry: String = flagcountrylist.FlagCard.flagimage[position]
    //var flagimageList: List<String> = flagcountrylist.map { it.flagimage }
    var flagsouthList: List<String> = flagcountrylist.map { it.flagsouth }
    var iflagsouth = flagsouthList[position]
    flagholder.flagname.text = iflagsouth
    flagholder.flagcardView.tag = position
    flagholder.flagcardView.setOnClickListener(flagitemClickListener)
    //flagholder.flagcardView.setOnLongClickListener(itemOnLongClickListener)

    when (position){
        0 -> flagholder.flagcountry.setImageResource(R.drawable.afgcol)
        1 -> flagholder.flagcountry.setImageResource(R.drawable.argsvk)
        2 -> flagholder.flagcountry.setImageResource(R.drawable.armche)
        3 -> flagholder.flagcountry.setImageResource(R.drawable.auttgo)
        4 -> flagholder.flagcountry.setImageResource(R.drawable.azepry)
        5 -> flagholder.flagcountry.setImageResource(R.drawable.bhrtur)
        6 -> flagholder.flagcountry.setImageResource(R.drawable.bratls)
        7 -> flagholder.flagcountry.setImageResource(R.drawable.bwasur)
        8 -> flagholder.flagcountry.setImageResource(R.drawable.cafbtn)
        9 -> flagholder.flagcountry.setImageResource(R.drawable.critun)
        10 -> flagholder.flagcountry.setImageResource(R.drawable.pandza)
        11 -> flagholder.flagcountry.setImageResource(R.drawable.persau)
        12 -> flagholder.flagcountry.setImageResource(R.drawable.svnago)
        13 -> flagholder.flagcountry.setImageResource(R.drawable.sweben)
        14 -> flagholder.flagcountry.setImageResource(R.drawable.tcdgbr)
        15 -> flagholder.flagcountry.setImageResource(R.drawable.thabol)
        16 -> flagholder.flagcountry.setImageResource(R.drawable.tjkdeu)
        17 -> flagholder.flagcountry.setImageResource(R.drawable.tkmbel)
        18 -> flagholder.flagcountry.setImageResource(R.drawable.tzablz)
        19 -> flagholder.flagcountry.setImageResource(R.drawable.ukrcmr)
        20 -> flagholder.flagcountry.setImageResource(R.drawable.uryblr)
        21 -> flagholder.flagcountry.setImageResource(R.drawable.venbgd)
        22 -> flagholder.flagcountry.setImageResource(R.drawable.vnmbfa)
        23 -> flagholder.flagcountry.setImageResource(R.drawable.yembih)
        24 -> flagholder.flagcountry.setImageResource(R.drawable.zmbchl)
        25 -> flagholder.flagcountry.setImageResource(R.drawable.zwealb)
    }
    //var iflagcard:String  = imagelist[position]
 //holder.flagcountry.setImageResource(iflagcard)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return flagcountrylist.size
    }
}


---------------------------------------
 //under new MainActivity file with function modified
 // i don't know what to do with the variable 
 // flagtempup, i use it to set the string in 
 // iflagtrigramdown, and i have te warning variable not used...


 package training.geography.triplerecyclerview

 import android.nfc.Tag
 import android.os.Bundle
 import android.view.View
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener
 import android.view.animation.Animation
 import android.view.animation.RotateAnimation
 import android.widget.ImageView
 import android.widget.Toast
 import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
 import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
 import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
 import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
 import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.item_flag.*

 data class FlagCard(var flagtrigramup: String, var flagtrigramdown: String,
                    var flagimage: String, var flagsouth: String, var  rotationpossible: Boolean=(true))

  data class CountryCard(val countrytrigram: String, val description: String)

  data class MapCard(var map_left_up: String,
               var map_right_up: String,
               var map_left_down: String,
               var map_right_down: String,
               var maps_img: String,
               var mapnorth: String)


  class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnClickListener {


var afg_col = FlagCard("col", "afg", "afgcol", "afg", true)
var arg_svk = FlagCard("arg", "svk", "argsvk", "svk", true)
var arm_che = FlagCard("che", "arm", "armche", "arm", true)
var aut_tgo = FlagCard("tgo", "aut", "auttgo", "aut", true)
var aze_pry = FlagCard("aze", "pry", "azepry", "pry", true)
var bhr_tur = FlagCard("tur", "bhr", "bhrtur", "bhr", true)
var bra_tls = FlagCard("tls", "bra", "bratls", "bra", true)
var bwa_sur = FlagCard("sur", "bwa", "bwasur", "bwa", true)
var caf_btn = FlagCard("btn", "caf", "cafbtn", "caf", true)
var cri_tun = FlagCard("cri", "tun", "critun", "tun", true)
var pan_dza = FlagCard("pan", "dza", "pandza", "dza", true)
var per_sau = FlagCard("per", "sau", "persau", "sau", true)
var svn_ago = FlagCard("svn", "ago", "svnago", "ago", true)
var swe_ben = FlagCard("swe", "ben", "sweben", "ben", true)
var tcd_gbr = FlagCard("tcd", "gbr", "tcdgbr", "gbr", true)
var tha_bol = FlagCard("tha", "bol", "thabol", "bol", true)
var tjk_deu = FlagCard("tjk", "deu", "tjkdeu", "deu", true)
var tkm_bel = FlagCard("tkm", "bel", "tkmbel", "bel", true)
var tza_blz = FlagCard("tza", "blz", "tzablz", "blz", true)
var ukr_cmr = FlagCard("ukr", "cmr", "ukrcmr", "cmr", true)
var ury_blr = FlagCard("ury", "blr", "uryblr", "blr", true)
var ven_bgd = FlagCard("ven", "bgd", "venbgd", "bgd", true)
var vnm_bfa = FlagCard("vnm", "bfa", "vnmbfa", "bfa", true)
var yem_bih = FlagCard("yem", "bih", "yembih", "bih", true)
var zmb_chl = FlagCard("zmb", "chl", "zmbchl", "chl", true)
var zwe_alb = FlagCard("zwe", "alb", "zwealb", "alb", true)

var afg = CountryCard("afg", "afg")
var ago = CountryCard("ago", "ago")
var alb = CountryCard("alb", "alb")
var arg = CountryCard("arg", "arg")
var arm = CountryCard("arm", "arm")
var aut = CountryCard("aut", "aut")
var aze = CountryCard("aze", "aze")
var bel = CountryCard("bel", "bel")
var bfa = CountryCard("bfa", "bfa")
var bhr = CountryCard("bhr", "bhr")
var bih = CountryCard("bih", "bih")
var blz = CountryCard("blz", "blz")
var bol = CountryCard("bol", "bol")
var bra = CountryCard("bra", "bra")
var btn = CountryCard("btn", "btn")
var bwa = CountryCard("bwa", "bwa")
var caf = CountryCard("caf", "caf")
var che = CountryCard("che", "che")
var chl = CountryCard("chl", "chl")
var cmr = CountryCard("cmr", "cmr")
var col = CountryCard("col", "col")
var cri = CountryCard("cri", "cri")
var deu = CountryCard("deu", "deu")
var gbr = CountryCard("gbr", "gbr")
var pan = CountryCard("pan", "pan")
var per = CountryCard("per", "per")
var pry = CountryCard("pry", "pry")
var sau = CountryCard("sau", "sau")
var sur = CountryCard("sur", "sur")
var svk = CountryCard("svk", "svk")
var svn = CountryCard("svn", "svn")
var swe = CountryCard("swe", "swe")
var tcd = CountryCard("tcd", "tcd")
var tgo = CountryCard("tgo", "tgo")
var tha = CountryCard("tha", "tha")
var tjk = CountryCard("tjk", "tjk")
var tkm = CountryCard("tkm", "tkm")
var tls = CountryCard("tls", "tls")
var tun = CountryCard("tun", "tun")
var tur = CountryCard("tur", "tur")
var tza = CountryCard("tza", "tza")
var ukr = CountryCard("ukr", "ukr")
var ury = CountryCard("ury", "ury")
var ven = CountryCard("ven", "ven")
var vnm = CountryCard("vnm", "vnm")
var yem = CountryCard("yem", "yem")
var zmb = CountryCard("zmb", "zmb")
var zwe = CountryCard("zwe", "zwe")

var arm_bol_gbr_ago = MapCard("arm", "bol", "gbr", "ago", "bol", "armbolgbrago")
var aze_bra_aut_ben = MapCard("aze", "bra", "aut", "ben", "bra", "azebraautben")
var bfa_blr_col_bgd = MapCard("bfa", "blr", "col", "bgd", "blr", "bfablrcolbgd")
var bwa_bel_bhr_chl = MapCard("bwa", "bel", "bhr", "chl", "bel", "bwabelbhrchl")
var caf_afg_alb_arg = MapCard("caf", "afg", "alb", "arg", "afg", "cafafgalbarg")
var che_tkm_tur_sur = MapCard("che", "tkm", "tur", "sur", "tkm", "chetkmtursur")
var cri_cmr_btn_bih = MapCard("cri", "cmr", "btn", "bih", "cmr", "cricmrbtnbih")
var sau_blz_deu_dza = MapCard("sau", "blz", "deu", "dza", "blz", "saublzdeudza")
var svn_tha_tcd_pry = MapCard("svn", "tha", "tcd", "pry", "tha", "svnthatcdpry")
var swe_tls_tgo_per = MapCard("swe", "tls", "tgo", "per", "tls", "swetlstgoper")
var tjk_pan_svk_tza = MapCard("tjk", "pan", "svk", "tza", "pan", "tjkpansvktza")
var ven_zwl_yem_ukr = MapCard("ven", "zwl", "yem", "ukr", "zwl", "venzwlyemukr")
var zmb_tur_ury_vnm = MapCard("zmb", "tur", "ury", "vnm", "tur", "zmbtururyvnm")


var flagcountrylist = listOf<FlagCard>(
    afg_col,
    arg_svk,
    arm_che,
    aut_tgo,
    aze_pry,
    bhr_tur,
    bra_tls,
    bwa_sur,
    caf_btn,
    cri_tun,
    pan_dza,
    per_sau,
    svn_ago,
    swe_ben,
    tcd_gbr,
    tha_bol,
    tjk_deu,
    tkm_bel,
    tza_blz,
    ukr_cmr,
    ury_blr,
    ven_bgd,
    vnm_bfa,
    yem_bih,
    zmb_chl,
    zwe_alb
)


val flagadapter = FlagAdapter(flagcountrylist, this)


var countryList = listOf<CountryCard>(
    afg,
    ago,
    alb,
    arg,
    arm,
    aut,
    aze,
    bel,
    bfa,
    bhr,
    bih,
    blz,
    blz,
    bol,
    bra,
    btn,
    bwa,
    caf,
    che,
    chl,
    cmr,
    col,
    cri,
    deu,
    gbr,
    pan,
    per,
    pry,
    sau,
    sur,
    svk,
    svn,
    swe,
    tcd,
    tgo,
    tha,
    tjk,
    tkm,
    tls,
    tun,
    tur,
    tza,
    ukr,
    ury,
    ven,
    vnm,
    yem,
    zmb,
    zwe
)
val countryadapter = CountryAdapter(countryList)


var mapcountrylist = listOf<MapCard>(
    arm_bol_gbr_ago,
    aze_bra_aut_ben,
    bfa_blr_col_bgd,
    bwa_bel_bhr_chl,
    caf_afg_alb_arg,
    che_tkm_tur_sur,
    cri_cmr_btn_bih,
    sau_blz_deu_dza,
    svn_tha_tcd_pry,
    swe_tls_tgo_per,
    tjk_pan_svk_tza,
    ven_zwl_yem_ukr,
    zmb_tur_ury_vnm
)
val mapadapter = MapAdapter(mapcountrylist)


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val flagsrecyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.flagsRecyclerView)
    flagsrecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, false)
    flagsrecyclerView.adapter = flagadapter


    val countryrecyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.countriesRecyclerView)
    countryrecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, false)
    countryrecyclerView.adapter = countryadapter


    val maprecyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.mapsRecyclerView)
    maprecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, false)
    maprecyclerView.adapter = mapadapter

}

  fun rotateFlagCard (flagCard: FlagCard, position: Int) : FlagCard {

    var flagtrigramuplist: List<String> = flagcountrylist.map{it.flagtrigramup }
    var iflagtrigramup : String = flagtrigramuplist[position]

    var flagimagelist = flagcountrylist.map{it.flagimage}
    var iflagimage = flagimagelist[position]
    var flagsouthlist = flagcountrylist.map { it.flagsouth }
    var iflagsouth = flagsouthlist[position]
    var rotationpossiblelist : List<Boolean> = flagcountrylist.map{ it.rotationpossible }
    var irotationpossible = rotationpossiblelist[position]
    var iflagimageView = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.flagcountry)

    when (position) {
        0 ->  iflagimageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.afgcol)
        1 ->  iflagimageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.argsvk)
        2 -> iflagimageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.armche)
        3 ->  iflagimageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.auttgo)
        4 -> iflagimageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.azepry)
        5 ->  iflagimageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.bhrtur)
        6 ->  iflagimageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.bratls)
        7 ->  iflagimageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.bwasur)
        8 ->  iflagimageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.cafbtn)
        9 ->  iflagimageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.critun)
        10 ->  iflagimageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.pandza)
        11 ->  iflagimageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.persau)
        12 ->  iflagimageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.svnago)
        13 ->  iflagimageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sweben)
        14 ->  iflagimageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.tcdgbr)
        15 ->  iflagimageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.thabol)
        16 ->  iflagimageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.tjkdeu)
        17 ->  iflagimageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.tkmbel)
        18 ->  iflagimageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.tzablz)
        19 ->  iflagimageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ukrcmr)
        20 ->  iflagimageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.uryblr)
        21 ->  iflagimageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.venbgd)
        22 ->  iflagimageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.vnmbfa)
        23 ->  iflagimageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.yembih)
        24 ->  iflagimageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.zmbchl)
        25 ->  iflagimageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.zwealb)
        else -> throw AssertionError()
    }

    if (irotationpossible)
        {
        iflagimageView.animate().apply {
            rotationBy(180f)
            duration = 1000L
            start()
          // permutation of values north south
            var flagtrigramdownlist :List<String> = flagcountrylist.map{it.flagtrigramdown}
            var iflagtrigramdown : String = flagtrigramdownlist[position]
        var flagtempup: String = iflagtrigramup
            var flagtempdown: String = iflagtrigramdown
        iflagtrigramup = iflagsouth
        //flagtempdown = flagtempup
            iflagtrigramdown = flagtempup

        var iflagCard = FlagCard( iflagtrigramup, iflagtrigramdown, iflagimage, iflagsouth, irotationpossible )
            return iflagCard
        }
    } else {
        return flagCard
        //Toast.makeText(this, "flag already matched country", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}


    override fun onClick(flagcardView: View) {
    if (flagcardView.tag != null) {
        val index = flagcardView.tag as Int
        var flagsouthList: List<String> = flagcountrylist.map{it.flagsouth }
        val flags = flagsouthList[index]
        Toast.makeText(this, "country : ${flags}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        var flagcard:FlagCard = flagcountrylist[index]
        rotateFlagCard (flagcard, index)

    }
   }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like nobody is interested by what is possible to do with RecyclerViews...

I still have the problem that when an imageView is clicked, this is the one at left which is rotating ! i can't understand what happens, examination in debugger shows the variables are ok, the index is position and do not change...

I tried to apply rotate function to the cardView, same result !

I modified the code in the function and replace the flagCard by iflagCard if rotation was done (because two flags, one up, one down, and of course the FlagCard is different... )

Here the new code :

```
if (irotationpossible)
    {
        iflagcardView.animate().apply {
            rotationBy(180f)
            duration = 1000L
            start()
            // permutation of values north south
            var flagtrigramdownlist :List<String> = flagcountrylist.map{it.flagtrigramdown}
            var iflagtrigramdown : String = flagtrigramdownlist[position]
            var flagtempup: String = iflagtrigramup
            var flagtempdown: String = iflagtrigramdown
            iflagtrigramup = iflagsouth
            iflagsouth = flagtempup
            iflagtrigramdown = flagtempup

            var iflagCard = FlagCard( iflagtrigramup, iflagtrigramdown, iflagimage, iflagsouth, irotationpossible )
            //flagcountrylist.toSet(position, iflagCard)
            //abstract operator fun set(position: Int, iflagCard: FlagCard): FlagCard
            flagcountrylist.removeAt(position)
            flagcountrylist.add(position, iflagCard)
            return iflagCard
        }
    } else {
        return flagCard
        //Toast.makeText(this, "flag already matched country", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
```

my question is now about the set function for mutableListOf in Kotlin :
i tried to use "  abstract operator fun set(index: Int, element: E): E  "
but couldn't build because of abstract !

Is there any other way than my solution to remove then add at the same index ?

Is there any experimented developper curious about the strange rotation in that app ?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d9o7fttLBxk

Why not the image with right index ?